# What's the difference between two QHeaderView signals?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qheaderview

On Qt doc website [in QHeaderView class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#sectionClicked) i found two signals with similar descriptions:

```
void QHeaderView::sectionDoubleClicked(int logicalIndex)
```

and

```
void QHeaderView::sectionHandleDoubleClicked(int logicalIndex)
```

what's the difference between the two of these? When should I use the first, and when the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the documentation strings are exactly the same,

> `void QHeaderView::sectionDoubleClicked(int logicalIndex)`
> This signal is emitted when a section is double-clicked. The section's logical index is specified by logicalIndex.

> `[signal]void QHeaderView::sectionHandleDoubleClicked(int logicalIndex)`
> This signal is emitted when a section is double-clicked. The section's logical index is specified by logicalIndex.

The signals **are** emitted in different cases. From [KDE's copy of Qt5](https://invent.kde.org/qt/qt/qtbase/-/blob/dev/src/widgets/itemviews/qheaderview.cpp#L2791),

```
void QHeaderView::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
...
    int handle = d->sectionHandleAt(pos);
    if (handle > -1 && sectionResizeMode(handle) == Interactive) {
        emit sectionHandleDoubleClicked(handle);
...
    } else {
        emit sectionDoubleClicked(logicalIndexAt(e->position().toPoint()));
    }
}
```

The documentation doesn't make it particularly clear, though, when "handles" might be present and when they aren't. At a guess, if your sections are resizable you may get a handle -- for resizing -- and then you can (double) click on either the handle or the section-body.